# Database connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

I'm just trying create and write to the database file.

I don't know why connection string has turned such:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\DATA_TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

With this connection string, I get this error:

> Error CS1009  Unrecognized escape sequence
>   XXX_DATABASE_TEST D:\FOLDER\XXX_DATABASE_TEST\Form1.cs

So I've changed "/" to "\":

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/User/Documents/DATA_TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Error has gone, form loads, but database is empty, doesn't writes. Can you help me figure out, what I'm doing wrong here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace XXX_DATABASE_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\DATA_TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

            con.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO testdata VALUES (Name, IDo, Gender) VALUES (@Name,@IDo,@Gender)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDo", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the button's click event wired up?  ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer for the number of records that were affected.  Check that value.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com. You need quotes around the pathname, and put the backslashes back in; Windows uses them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your connection string have to be like this :

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\DATA_TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

And for `localdb`, you can do something like this too :

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .;Initial Catalog = DATA_TEST;Integrated Security = True")
```